# Transform a helm dict into a list

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I'm using a Helm chart to control what environment variables are set for a certain container in a deployment.

In my `Values.yaml`, I have an entry called `env` which is a dictionary:

```yaml
image:
  repository: xxxx.yyyyy.com/myimage
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  # Enviroment variables that will be passed to the container.
  env: {}
```

Now, I'll pass variables to the `env` dict using `--set`:

```yaml
helm upgrade mydeployment chart --set env.VARIABLE=test
```

However, this must be transformed into a list to adhere to Kubernetes yaml:

```yaml
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
          image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag | default .Chart.AppVersion }}"
          imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
          # This should come from that dict
          env:
            - name: VARIABLE
              value: "test"
```

I don't know how to use the template language from Helm (sprig / go) to achieve that. Is it even possible?

Comment: I did not get your question. You have many env variables set in `env` and you want to create those in `spec.template.spec.containers.env`? You just need to loop in that case

Answer (score 1):

To iterate through the map, the core Go [text/template](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template) language provides a `range` keyword that can iterate through maps or arrays.

```
{{ range $key, $value := .Values.env }}
...
{{ end }}
```

Inside of this you can put arbitrary text.  Helm doesn't require this to be any particular kind of YAML construct, just so long as the final result is valid YAML.  For this setup a typical loop would look like

```yaml
env:
{{- range $key, $value := .Values.env }}
  - name: {{ quote $key }}
    value: {{ quote $value }}
{{- end }}
```

You do need to be careful with indentation here.  As a rule of thumb it often will work to include a `-` "swallow whitespace" indicator inside the open `{{` and to not include one inside the close `}}`.  The `- name:` must be at least as indented as the `env:` above it (ignoring the `range` line), and `value:` must be aligned with `name:`.  I might put all of the template-language lines (the `range` and `end`) starting at the first column, even if they're embedded in a structure that's nested more.

```yaml
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: {{ template "chart.fullname" . }}
          env:
{{- range $key, $value := .Values.env }}
            - name: {{ quote $key }}
              value: {{ quote $value }}
{{- end }}
          image: {{ .Values.registry }}/{{ .Values.image }}:{{ .Values.tag }}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error on the range line: `too many declarations in command`. Do you know what it is? To be honest, I've not researched it yet.

Comment: My first two examples had incorrect syntax for the `range` loop (the last one was correct).  I've fixed this.