# Convert dictionary in Helm chart template

Tags: go, templates, kubernetes-helm

I want to convert dictionary to dictionary (Variable) in Helm chart, not related to the Template rendering

```yaml
# Values.yaml
proxy:
  public:
    alias: proxy-public.somedomain.com
    address: 123.123.123.123
  private:
    alias: proxy-private.somedomain.com
    address: 172.25.8.16
```

I want to convert to another dictionary, dict comprehension/jq/Terraform style:

```golang
{{- $aliases := ... ???? -}}
```

So structure is,

```json
{public: proxy-"public.somedomain.com", private: "proxy-private.somedomain.com"}
```

Having hard time making proper syntax

Purpose is, to have this dictionary converted to Json down the line

```yaml
data:
  aliases: {{ $aliases | toJson | quote }}
```

Which is different from looping and rendering it to the template, like [in this SO anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69829036/transform-a-helm-dict-into-a-list), for example:

Comment: Helm by and large doesn't have operations like this.  I might approach this by writing a template that directly takes in the values object and produces a JSON string as its output, without necessarily using an intermediate object and `toJson`.